# Generate the post title from ACF fields

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I want to generate post title from first name and last name which are two fields. The posts are generated in WS Form and saved with no title.

I tried this code however it does not seem to work.
Any thoughts?!

```
    function set_post_title_from_acf($post_id){

        $my_post = array();
        $my_post['ID'] = $post_id

        if (get_post_type($post_id) == 'staff'){

            $first_name = get_field('first_name',$post_id);
            $last_name = get_field('last_name',$post_id);

            $my_title = $first_name . ' ' . $last_name;
            $my_post['post_title'] = $my_title;
            $my_slug = sanitize_title($my_title);
            $my_post['post_name'] = $my_slug;
            wp_update_post($my_post);

        }

    }
    add_action('save_post','set_post_title_from_acf',20);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$post_id` value get in save_post hook might be `revision ID`. So to retrieve real post ID, you can use this function `wp_is_post_revision()`

Try to change your code as follows,

```
function set_post_title_from_acf($post_id) {
    
    // If this is a revision, get real post ID
    if ( $parent_id = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) 
        $post_id = $parent_id;

    $my_post = array();
    $my_post['ID'] = $post_id;

    if (get_post_type($post_id) == 'staff') {

        $first_name = get_field('first_name', $post_id);
        $last_name = get_field('last_name', $post_id);

        $my_title = $first_name . ' ' . $last_name;
        $my_post['post_title'] = $my_title;
        $my_slug = sanitize_title($my_title);
        $my_post['post_name'] = $my_slug;
        
        // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
        remove_action( 'save_post', 'set_post_title_from_acf' );
        
        wp_update_post($my_post);
        
        // re-hook this function
        add_action( 'save_post', 'set_post_title_from_acf' );
        
        
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'set_post_title_from_acf');
```

Nb: If we are calling wp_update_post() inside save_post hook, it will create an infinite loop. To avoid this, unhook the function before calling the function and then re-hook it as in the above code.